# 500 Error on IIS front end

Tags: iis, error-500

this is the error page
[image]

I can see the backend (I mean the Expression Engine control panel works perfect) but the front (the web site show a 500 error).

I add this to the web.config

and now the 500 error turns to this:

[image]

Comment: So have you tried repairing the table?

Comment: yes! and repairing the table fix my issue, thank you.